# Save results in YAML file with python

Tags: python, numpy, yaml

I'm stuck in this little problem after an hour of searching previous answer. 
I want to store matrices from my code in .yaml file

What I obtain from my code

```
Matrix
[[  1.00665266e+03   0.00000000e+00   5.08285432e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.01086937e+03   3.45995536e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
```

How I tried to save this matrix (`mtx` is the shorter name in my code)

```
fname = "calibrationC300.yaml"

data = dict(
    Matrix = mtx,
)

with open(fname, "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

But what I read in my YAML file is totally wrong (just only bad conversion?)

```
Matrix: !!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct
  args:
  - &id001 !!python/name:numpy.ndarray ''
  - !!python/tuple [0]
  - b
  state: !!python/tuple
  - 1
  - !!python/tuple [3, 3]
  - !!python/object/apply:numpy.dtype
    args: [f8, 0, 1]
    state: !!python/tuple [3, <, null, null, null, -1, -1, 0]
  - false
  - !!binary |
    cWM87e1YkEAAAAAAAAAAAIUEEyb5SH1AAAAAAAAAAACp/Z3yc2qQQFv0vPqb5nZAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPA/
```

It is the first time I use Yaml files, what am I doing wrong?
Is there a method to obtain the matrix in the simple form (as I obtain it from the code) in the yaml file?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What's your aim - to get something that's suitable for input to a numpy script, something portable that's suitable for input to a different tool, or something human readable?

Comment: @JohnCarter preferrable all of these three things. For input for my numpy script I just solved with numpy.savez

Comment: Assuming you are using PyYAML, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75508284/2095383

Answer (score 7):

The difference is between float and numpy.float64. Yaml uses more sophisticated way to represent numpy.float64. You can change to float if you like more readble yaml. See the following example:

```
print(yaml.dump({'test': 1, 'data':float(0.2)}, default_flow_style=False))
print(yaml.dump({'test': 2, 'data':numpy.float64(0.2)}, default_flow_style=False))
```

Output are:

```
data: 0.2

test: 1

data: !!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar
- !!python/object/apply:numpy.dtype
  args:
  - f8
  - 0
  - 1
  state: !!python/tuple
  - 3
  - <
  - null
  - null
  - null
  - -1
  - -1
  - 0
- !!binary |
  mpmZmZmZyT8=

test: 2
```

Comment: df.to_dict('records') can convert a dataframe to plain python dictionary

Answer (score 4):

The only thing wrong here seems to be your expectation of how `numpy` internals can and should be dumped to YAML.

An easy check to see that what you have gotten as YAML is correct, is to `load` what you `dump`-ed:

```
import ruamel.yaml
import numpy
import pprint

mtx = [[1.00665266e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 5.08285432e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 1.01086937e+03, 3.45995536e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00],]

data = dict(Matrix=mtx)

yaml_str = ruamel.yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)
data = ruamel.yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'Matrix': [[1006.65266, 0.0, 508.285432], [0.0, 1010.86937, 345.995536], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]}
```

The special types that `numpy` uses are **not** dumped as simple (and readable) YAML, there is no guarantee that that could be reloaded. It might be possible for some constructs, although it easily leads to ambiguity, and AFAIK simplification it is not done for any of the `numpy` types.

Of course you can dump that YAML without having `numpy` supply its restore information, by doing:

```
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Matrix:
- - 1006.65266
  - 0.0
  - 508.285432
- - 0.0
  - 1010.86937
  - 345.995536
- - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0
```

much more readable, but not something that will ever become a numpy.multiarray *automatically* when you `load()` it again from its YAML representation.

Comment: In your example, `mtx` is not a `np.multiarray` but a regular list (and `np.multiarray` is overwritten by this list). You surely did mean `mtx = numpy.multiarray([[...], ...])`.

Comment: @moi I certainly did not mean `mtx = numpy.multiarray([[...], ...])`, as that would dump exactly the non-readable YAML the OP complained about and would not get you the result as presented. Of course `mtx` is not an `np.multiarray`, why would they be? They just get assigned the same value in a multiple-assignment statement. You can of course argue that assigning to np.multiarray serves no purpose here, but that is something entirely different.

Comment: OK, I understand. So if it serves no purpose, you might want to remove it from your answer as it confuses people (at least me).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a expert as well, but the produced yaml seems correct. You can see dat the the primitive types are rendered well by default. For the others you might have to take some action. Read here in the  [documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers).

Good luck!

(I don't have enough rep. to comment, otherwise I would leave this post as a comment.)

Comment: @I will try to look your link, thank you. Do you know if there Is a method to save my matrix in the same form as I obtain it in my code? (I upvote your answer so now you have enough reputation to comment!)

Comment: From the documentation it seems that you have to make your own subclass of the yaml.YAMLObject, and specify the __repr__, __init__ and yaml_tag. I would think it's allready available somewhere... but I can't find it. 

If you just want to serialize, you might convert the matrix to a nested list?

Comment: I can't find an example too. I want to save my matrix as a matrix in order to load it into another script. I start to wonder if YAML is not the right choice...

Comment: Personally, I would only use yaml for readability. Otherwise use json or pickle.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been facing the same issue and the way to deal with it is to add a representer for custom types.

For example, this will convert `np.ndarray` to python `list` before dumping them to disk:

```py
yaml.add_representer(np.ndarray, lambda dumper, array: dumper.represent_list(array.tolist()))
```