# Dump NumPy Array to YAML as regular list

Tags: python, numpy, yaml, pyyaml

When using PyYAML to safe a NumPy array in a YAML file, it by default adds a whole lot of metadata such that it can restore the actual array when loading the file.  Example:

```py
import numpy as np
import yaml

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(yaml.dump(a))
```

results in

```
!!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct
args:
- !!python/name:numpy.ndarray ''
- !!python/tuple
  - 0
- !!binary |
  Yg==
state: !!python/tuple
- 1
- !!python/tuple
  - 3
- !!python/object/apply:numpy.dtype
  args:
  - i8
  - false
  - true
  state: !!python/tuple
  - 3
  - <
  - null
  - null
  - null
  - -1
  - -1
  - 0
- false
- !!binary |
  AQAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAA
```

However, I don't care about restoring the exact NumPy array but instead need the resulting YAML to be compatible with other applications.  Therefore, I want the array to be dumped as a normal sequence, i.e. like this:

```
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

Is there a way to tell PyYAML to handle NumPy arrays like standard lists without having to convert every array manually?

Answer (score 6):

It can be done by adding a custom "representer" that converts the array to a list:

```py
import numpy as np
import yaml

def ndarray_representer(dumper: yaml.Dumper, array: np.ndarray) -> yaml.Node:
    return dumper.represent_list(array.tolist())

yaml.add_representer(np.ndarray, ndarray_representer)

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(yaml.dump(a))
```

Resulting output:

```
- 1
- 2
- 3
```